# Oracle APEX: Turn off character escaping inside an Interactive Grid select list

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with one column set as select list and with some LOV entries like `"Salesman & Manager"`.

Before selecting it, the value is displayed as `"Salesman & Manager"` correctly but it changes to `"Salesman &amp; Manager"` inside the grid afterwards. Is there any workaround for this?

Since I want this column to be editable, I can not just change the column's type to display only and turn off special character escaping.

Comment: This is a known bug - according to Oracle the APEX team is tracking this issue. I'd say the only workaround would be to replace the character with something else, e.g. `'and'`.

Comment: we are on 19.2 and still facing same issue. can you direct me to this documented bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced this on the Oracle APEX 19.1 Early Adopter environment and it looks like, that Oracle has fixed this issue with the character escaping. So the solution is to wait and adopt to Oracle 19.1 when it gets released.

Thanks to Jeffrey for his hint.

Comment: we are on 19.2 and it's not fixed yet.